# How can I connect a CentOS Hyper V guest OS to the smartcard reader on my physical machine?

Tags: hyper-v, usb, smartcard

I'm running Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V Manager 10. On that Hyper-V I'm running a guest CentOS 7 VM.

I'd like an application on that CentOS VM to read a smartcard that's physically inserted into a card reader on my host machine.

I've got both a Broadcom smartcard reader in the laptop itself, and a Dell smartcard reader in my USB keyboard.

I've seen references to "smartcard device redirection" over RDP, but RDP obviously isn't going to work to a Linux box.

Is there any way to do this?